# Мультиязычный интерфейс

Tags: .net, winforms, локализация

Хочу создать мультиязычный интерфейс. Переписывать весь код, заменяя весь текст на переменные из собственно созданного файла ресурсов, мне было лень. Я воспользовался классом [CultureInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture(v=vs.110).aspx). Также мне помог [урок на ютубе](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-2ksI53bPtg).
В итоге сделать мультиязычный интерфейс у меня получилось, однако язык интерфейса меняется только в новом экземпляре формы. Никакие update, resumlayout, refresh не обновляют текст на форме( возможно конечно я не для всех методов знаю назначение, но я попробовал).

Для простоты тестирования, я повесил это все на кнопку с кодом:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = New CultureInfo("en-150")
Dim t As New Form1
t.Show()
```

Comment: Мне кажется следует разделить вопрос на два независимых: 1) "У меня проблема с мультиязычностью" и 2) "Какой способ организации мультиязычности вы считаете лучшим?"

Comment: Можно согласится, но меня больше волнует основной вопрос. Однако с меткой vb.net не соглашусь.

Comment: @adrug: а какой вопрос у вас основной? Если про свой код, то второй вопрос предлагаю удалить, чтобы не провоцировать субъективные ответы.

Comment: Хорошо, уберу. Пусть не смущает он вас больше.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно создать `ComponentResourceManager`, передав ему тип формы, и рекурсивно вызвать `ApplyResources` для всех контролов. Примерно так:

```
Private Shared Sub ChangeLanguage()
    For Each frm As Form In Application.OpenForms
        LocalizeForm(frm)
    Next
End Sub

Private Shared Sub LocalizeForm(frm As Form)
    Dim manager = New ComponentResourceManager(frm.GetType())
    manager.ApplyResources(frm, "$this")
    ApplyResources(manager, frm.Controls)
End Sub

Private Shared Sub ApplyResources(manager As ComponentResourceManager, ctls As Control.ControlCollection)
    For Each ctl As Control In ctls
        manager.ApplyResources(ctl, ctl.Name)
        ApplyResources(manager, ctl.Controls)
    Next
End Sub
```

Применять примерно так:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = New CultureInfo("ru-ru")
ChangeLanguage()
```

Вариант на C#:

```
private static void ChangeLanguage()
{
    foreach (Form frm in Application.OpenForms)
    {
        LocalizeForm(frm);
    }
}

private static void LocalizeForm(Form frm)
{
    var manager = new ComponentResourceManager(frm.GetType());
    manager.ApplyResources(frm, "$this");
    ApplyResources(manager, frm.Controls);
}

private static void ApplyResources(ComponentResourceManager manager, Control.ControlCollection ctls)
{
    foreach (Control ctl in ctls)
    {
        manager.ApplyResources(ctl, ctl.Name);
        ApplyResources(manager, ctl.Controls);
    }
}
```

<sub>код честно взят с [enSO, Change language at runtime in C# winform](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21068497/1988244)</sub>

Comment: Да не стоило варианта на vb. Разобрался.
Очень даже устраивает меня этот вариант.